# Stop Build Aosp FAILED: out/target/product/dm1q/vendor.img

Tags: android

I'm this error during aosp build. This is log out:
FAILED: out/target/product/dm1q/vendor.img
/bin/bash -c "(mkdir -p out/target/product/dm1q/vendor ) && (mkdir -p out/target/product/dm1q/obj/PACKAGING/vendor_intermediates && rm -rf out/target/product/dm1q/obj/PACKAGING/vendor_intermediates/vendor_image_info.txt ) && (echo "vendor_fs_type=ext4" >>  out/target/product/dm1q/obj/PACKAGING/vendor_intermediates/vendor_image_info.txt ) && (echo "vendor_disable_sparse=true" >>  out/target/product/dm1q/obj/PACKAGING/vendor_intermediates/vendor_image_info.txt ) && (echo "vendor_selinux_fc=out/target/product/dm1q/obj/ETC/file_contexts.bin_intermediates/file_contexts.bin" >>  out/target/product/dm1q/obj/PACKAGING/vendor_intermediates/vendor_image_info.txt ) && (echo "building_vendor_image=true" >>  out/target/product/dm1q/obj/PACKAGING/vendor_intermediates/vendor_image_info.txt ) && (echo "ext_mkuserimg=mkuserimg_mke2fs" >>  out/target/product/dm1q/obj/PACKAGING/vendor_intermediates/vendor_image_info.txt ) && (echo "fs_type=ext4" >>  out/target/product/dm1q/obj/PACKAGING/vendor_intermediates/vendor_image_info.txt ) && (echo "extfs_sparse_flag=-s" >>  out/target/product/dm1q/obj/PACKAGING/vendor_intermediates/vendor_image_info.txt ) && (echo "erofs_sparse_flag=-s" >>  out/target/product/dm1q/obj/PACKAGING/vendor_intermediates/vendor_image_info.txt ) && (echo "squashfs_sparse_flag=-s" >>  out/target/product/dm1q/obj/PACKAGING/vendor_intermediates/vendor_image_info.txt ) && (echo "f2fs_sparse_flag=-S" >>  out/target/product/dm1q/obj/PACKAGING/vendor_intermediates/vendor_image_info.txt ) && (echo "avb_avbtool=avbtool" >>  out/target/product/dm1q/obj/PACKAGING/vendor_intermediates/vendor_image_info.txt ) && (echo "avb_vendor_hashtree_enable=true" >>  out/target/product/dm1q/obj/PACKAGING/vendor_intermediates/vendor_image_info.txt ) && (echo "avb_vendor_add_hashtree_footer_args=--hash_algorithm sha256 --prop com.android.build.vendor.os_version:14 --prop com.android.build.vendor.fingerprint:$(cat out/target/product/dm1q/build_fingerprint.txt) --prop com.android.build.vendor.security_patch:2023-08-05" >>  out/target/product/dm1q/obj/PACKAGING/vendor_intermediates/vendor_image_info.txt ) && (echo "root_dir=out/target/product/dm1q/root" >>  out/target/product/dm1q/obj/PACKAGING/vendor_intermediates/vendor_image_info.txt ) && (echo "use_dynamic_partition_size=true" >>  out/target/product/dm1q/obj/PACKAGING/vendor_intermediates/vendor_image_info.txt ) && (echo "skip_fsck=true" >>  out/target/product/dm1q/obj/PACKAGING/vendor_intermediates/vendor_image_info.txt ) && (sort -o  out/target/product/dm1q/obj/PACKAGING/vendor_intermediates/vendor_image_info.txt  out/target/product/dm1q/obj/PACKAGING/vendor_intermediates/vendor_image_info.txt ) && (PATH=out/host/linux-x86/bin/:system/extras/ext4_utils/:$PATH out/host/linux-x86/bin/build_image --input-directory-filter-file out/target/product/dm1q/obj/PACKAGING/vendor_intermediates/file_list.txt out/target/product/dm1q/vendor out/target/product/dm1q/obj/PACKAGING/vendor_intermediates/vendor_image_info.txt out/target/product/dm1q/vendor.img out/target/product/dm1q/system ) && (true )"
firmware/: not normalized
13:44:18 ninja failed with: exit status 1

Any suggestion?

Expected:
Build's complete successfull!